# Two dimensional array in SD Card is too slow

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, matrix, sd-card

I'm working on a project which processes images in Java. Now I have a problem with too much MB. I have the matrix, about 70,000 rows and 500 columns, and it is stored on the SD Card. Accessing the rows and columns is too slow because there is not a two dimensional array or something like that.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: It is pretty difficult to understand what is being asked here. Are you trying to access a database or a file? Do you really need to open all of it at once? Lastly, mobile does have its limitation.. trying to read the entire contents of large files has limitations that can not always be worked around, especially on mobile.

Comment: I trying to ACCES a databases...problem is for saving columns reading rows etc. for tho dimensional array it will be faster...but how Can i make it ? maybe in the C+?

Comment: There still is not enough information to answer this question. You should really evaluate your question and provide more useful information. We still have no idea how you are actually accessing the data. We can only assume that maybe it is sqlite? What does your query look like, a poorly written query on a large table will not perform well. Lastly what does you data look like. You really need to provide significantly more information for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i Use sqlite, ok for the points:
1. firts I make "matrix" from the columns -on the SD card
2. fisrt method i need all rows from "matrix"-(75000!)-very slow
3. next method I need to acces to some choosen rows aprox.-56% of all.,-and save to another temp matrix like rows /there will be ok, but!
4. on this last method i need from the temp Matirx Columns or only to points from temp matrix -1,1;2,2;2.1 etc..but the columns will be 10 times better! There is problem when I save columns and read rows...becouse...thereinot two dimensional array r matrix object like in Jama:, I need some trick , or somethink.